# Geting data-index of images with same className by using eventListener

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Let's assume that I have ten images with different `data-index` but same `class` and `src` such as:

```
<img src="images/image.png"  class="image" data-index="${index})">
```

And I want to reach the `data-index` of clicked image with `eventListener`

```
const image= document.getElementsByClassName('image');

image.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', function() {
     console.log(el.getAttribute('data-index'));

}));
```

But, I get the error which says `image.forEach is not a function`. How can I solve this? How can I get the `data-index` of clicked image. This task needed to be done with `eventListener`. It cannot be done with `onClick` because some other parts are failing otherwise. Also, these images are printed by using innerHTML in JS code.

So basically, I have images with same attributes but only not `data-index`. How can I reach the `data-index` of clicked image?

Comment: Where is `remove` in your existing code?

Comment: Edited. It was a mistake.

Comment: also highly advice not to use `getElementsByClassName` anymore. Use `querySelector` or `querySelectorAll` instead.

Comment: Use `Array.from()` to convert to an array.

Comment: if you do `console.log(image)` what do you get?

Comment: `HTMLCollection(3) [img.image, img.image, img.image]
length: 0
[[Prototype]]: HTMLCollection`